# Data Insertion in table giving error in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm retrieving some data from different Views and then inserting the data into a table. But whenever I press the insert button the application crashes and says "Application stopped responding". I have spent like 2 hours on this and I'm completely stuck here. This is my first application using Sqlite in android.

I have about 10 classes and different variables are coming from different classes so cannot post the complete java code. **Here is the java code causing the problem, logcat shows error at the execSQL statement within the if**.

*insTabVal* is an Extra that comes with the Intent and it tells in which Table to put the data, *MainActivity* is also not null and *db* is SQLite Database object which is also open. All the *Val variables* within the SQL query are the values to be inserted in the table and come from different views and they are also not null.

```
 btnInsert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getValues();
            if(b.getString("insTableVal").equals("Donor")){
                MainActivity.db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Donor VALUES("+IdVal+","+NameVal+","+AgeVal+","+GenderVal+","+BGVal+");");
            }
            else if(b.getString("insTableVal").equals("Recipient")){
                MainActivity.db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Recipient VALUES("+IdVal+","+NameVal+","+AgeVal+","+GenderVal+","+BGVal+");");
            }
        }
    });
```

This is the logcat

```
12-31 06:50:00.038 13562-13562/com.example.bilalrafique.bloodbankmanagementsystem E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                Process: com.example.bilalrafique.bloodbankmanagementsystem, PID: 13562
                                                                                                java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                                    at com.example.bilalrafique.bloodbankmanagementsystem.DnRInsertion$1.onClick(DnRInsertion.java:34)
                                                                                                    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4466)
                                                                                                    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18537)
                                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5102)
                                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
                                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
                                                                                                    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Where is the Null pointer Exception occuring. I can't figure out.

P.S [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors) I have also checked this question but this explains how to look for error through stack trace. I already know that error is at line no 34 and it is null pointer exception. I want to know that how can an Insert statement throw null pointer exception even when all of the variables going in are not null.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: b.getString("insTableVal") may be null. What's at DnRInsertion.java line 34?

Comment: No it is not null because logcat shows the error on the line in which I'm inserting data in the if statement.

Comment: Is MainActivity.db null?

Comment: Use the debugger. Put a breakpoint on DnRInsertion.java line 34 and examine all variables and all returned expressions from nested function calls.

Comment: post your whole java file otherwise your issue want be solved. @BilalRafique